# Illegal access error after upgrading version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot app. Using version `2.7.16`.

I was on Java version `8`. Moved to Java version `11` now.

When I run the app, getting the error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$6: ClassLoader
> mismatch for [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor]: JVM
> should be started with --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED for
> ClassLoader.defineClass to be accessible on
> org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader; consider
> co-locating the affected class in that target ClassLoader instead.
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module java.base does not
> open java.util.concurrent to unnamed module

I updated the pom file as follows. But the error remains. Why?

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--add-opens</arg>
                        <arg>add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    // other plugins
    <plugins>
        spring-boot-maven-plugin
        maven-resources-plugin
        maven-assembly-plugin
        jacoco-maven-plugin
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Using Java 11, running it via Terminal using command:

```bash
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Comment: @Jorn Pls see the code block. That's what I've tried.

Comment: Did start the jvm with --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED like the error message says?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the "add-opens=" part from the second argument? Could you try setting your JDK source and target versions to 11 in the plugin config?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Produces same error when I removed add-opens from 2nd arg. Also do have the following in the POM file.   <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have modified the `maven-compiler-plugin` but the `--add-opens` is neededd at run-time.  Since you run the app through the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` the correct configuration is:

```xml
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
         <jvmArguments>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</jvmArguments>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Tried this, produces same error.

Comment: Put that block in `<pluginManagement>`.